# Does the distance from the portal matter when upgrading a resonator?

Tags: ingress

For example, say I notice a portal with a good deployment of low level resonators at the maximum radius from the portal center.

If I stand on the center and upgrade a resonator, will the upgraded resonator be re-located right next to the portal, or does it remain at the maximum radius?

Answer (score 23):

The upgraded resonator stays where it was when it was first deployed.